# Formal limit involving sin(x)

Tags: limits

$ax = \frac{\sin(x)}{20x + 1}$
I am trying to prove that the limit of $ax$ as $x$ approaches infinity is 0.

I am not sure what to do algebraically after starting with $|\frac{\sin(x)}{(20x+1)}-0|<\epsilon$.
.

Comment: If you are interested in the proof directly from definition of limit, ([tag:epsilon-delta]) tag would be suitable for your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof should not start with
$$\Bigl|\frac{\sin x}{20x+1}-0\Bigr|<\epsilon\ ,$$
it should finish with that.

Your proof should follow the logic of the definition step by step.  In outline, it should be as follows

> Let $\epsilon>0$.
>   Choose $M=\cdots\,$.
>   Suppose $x>M$.  Then
>   $$\Bigl|\frac{\sin x}{20x+1}-0\Bigr|=\cdots<\epsilon\ .$$

Of course the problem at this stage is that bits have been left out: the choice of $M$ and the algebraic working.  To figure out these bits you can work backwards:
$$\eqalign{
  \Bigl|\frac{\sin x}{20x+1}-0\Bigr|
  &=\Bigl|\frac{\sin x}{20x+1}\Bigr|\cr
  &\le\frac1{20x+1}\qquad\hbox{if $20x+1>0$}\cr
  &<\frac{1}{20x}\cr
  &<\frac{1}{20M}\ .\cr}$$
Now if
$$\frac{1}{20M}=\epsilon$$
then we have exactly what we want, so in the above proof we fill in the choice $M=1/(20\epsilon)$ and complete the algebra.

Hope this helps.