# Prove that f is uniformly continuous

Tags: calculus, uniform-continuity

I found this example of uniformly continuous but had a question regarding a step.

Let $S=R$ and $f(x)=3x+7$. Then $f$ is uniformly continuous on $S$.

Proof: Choose $\epsilon > 0$. Let $\delta= \frac{\epsilon}{3}.$Choose $x_o \in R.$ Choose $x\in R$ Assume $|x-x_o| < \delta$. Then

$|f(x)-f(x_o)|=|(3x+7)-(3x_o+7)|=3|x-x_o| < 3\delta= \epsilon$

My question is how do we get $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{3}$? Is this unique? Or what thought process must I have to have a delta?

Comment: By the way, $\delta$ won't be unique. Once you find a $\delta$ that works, any $\delta' \in (0,\delta)$ would also work.

Comment: but how can I find a $\delta$ I know that $\delta=\delta(\epsilon)$, so it must be a $\delta$ that is >0?

Comment: You effectively want to find a $\delta = \delta(\epsilon)$ such that if $|x - x_0|< \delta$, then $|f(x)-f(x_0)| < \delta$. In fact, you have already done this, just make sure you are clear on why it works. :) Basically we go through the process you did to come up with what $\delta$ should be. However, this should be considered "rough working", and when we write out the proof, we should write it "going forwards" by presenting our $\delta$ value at the start (basically as though we pulled it out of thin air).

Comment: Do you have any links that have examples so I can understand a little bit better? The $\delta=\frac{\epsilon}{3}$ is still confusing me.

Comment: There are probably many examples of writing proofs of limits using the formal definition (which is similar in nature to the proof you are writing). Try searching for things like "epsilon delta proof" on MSE. Here is one example: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1197917/formal-limit-involving-sinx

Comment: Thank you, will research that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By reverse-engineering. Let $S(e)$ be the sentence  $$\forall x,y\;(\;|x-y|<d\implies |f(x)-f(y)<e\;).$$  See what $S(e)$ implies about $d,$ for a given $e>0.$ We find that it implies $d\le e/3.$  If the implication is 2-way ("$\iff$") then  we will  have $d\le e/3\implies S(e),$ and we're done. If we're not sure that it's 2-way, then we know that $|x-y|<e/3$ is necessary, and more work is needed to see whether it is also sufficient.

In this Q we have $$S(e)\iff [\,\forall x,y\;(|x-y|<d\implies 3|x-y|<e)\,] \iff  d\le e/3.$$

Given $e>0,$ this value $e/3$ is the largest possible $d$ that makes $S(e)$ true.  Some students get mired in details in problems like this by trying to find the largest possible $d,$ when it doesn't matter. $S(e)$ is also true if $d=e/1000000000 .$